# Fancybox onclose put content

Tags: php, jquery, fancybox

I have form with few input box, for example:

```
FORM START
News -> input
News picture -> input (id="newspics", name="news_picture")
Add -> submit button

"Hyperlink Set picture" -> opening Fancy box window with gallery (table, 5*5, 25 pictures), images must be hyperlinked with unique id

FORM END
```

I need communication between Fancy box onclose() and my input (news_picture), when user click to picture I need: closing fancy box, putting id number to my input (news picture). Please if anybody help me.

Update:
I solved problem.

I make little php script, fwrite function write id number when user click to addpicture.php?id=$id in fancy box

After this, I get them, code:

```
'onClosed'          : function() {
jQuery.get('aa.txt',function(data){
alert(data);
});
}
```

Comment: While I agree this isn't a great question, if you're going to downvote, you should post a comment indicating why, so as to help the poster improve the question such that they can actually get an answer.

Comment: Let's u-pvote to counterattack ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass php variables into a fancybox callback you can do

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
  "onClosed" : function(){
    $("#input_selector").val(<?php echo $phpVariable; ?>);
    // or add an ID attribute
    // $("#input_selector").attr("id", ""+<?php echo $phpVariable; ?>+"");
  }
});
```

... the example above is to get you an idea how to do it, its not a recipe ;)

Bear in mind that `onClosed` is a callback for fancybox v1.3.4 ... if yours is v2.x use `afterClose` instead.

Comment: Thank for question, but how I can connect my hyperlink in fancybox (when user click picture, app must close fancybox and put ID), for example now i use this:

<script type="text/javascript">
 function addTextTag(text){
    document.getElementById('text_tag_input').value += text;
   }
 </script>

and hyperlink
<a href="#" onClick="addTextTag('22'); return false">Picture</a>

Comment: I was now testing my code, I put this code, this test "add for test" string work when i close fancybox, now I need hyperlink for (at same time):
send unique id when click
close fancy box<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#putpicture").fancybox({
            'width': 500,
            'height': 180,

            'type': 'iframe',

            'onClosed': function () {
                addTextTag('ss');
            }


        });
    });
</script>